# Is there a way to attach more than one cloud function to a specific collection in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a trigger to my Firestore collection. So I need to use more than one cloud function here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? It may be helpful to add some pseudo-code to your question such as "when a document is updated, I want to do X and do Y", "when a document is deleted, I want to do Z".

Comment: Yup, there should be no issue attaching multiple Cloud Functions to the same collection. If you're having trouble making this work, edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found out the answer from somewhere else. Actually I can just add different cloud functions and call one documents through all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are any limit to how many cloud functions you can invoke. It depends on how much you're willing to pay.

Comment: Question is about "way to attach more cloud code" but your answer says about limit not anything about how it can be done.